# Adding the total number of pages to the page number in Sejda

Tags: batch-file, sejda

I'm using the sejda-console to add page numbers to a PDF and I would like to include the total number of pages. For example, if my PDF has 20 pages, I would like it to say "page 1 of 20" on the first page and so on.

How can I do this with sejda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using Sejda 2.x, here's an example:

```
./bin/sejda-console setheaderfooter -f input.pdf -o /tmp/output.pdf --pageRange all --verticalAlign bottom --horizontalAlign center --label "Page [PAGE_OF_TOTAL]"
```

There's no released 2.x version yet, so for the time being you'd need to build it from source:

https://github.com/torakiki/sejda

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply :) I tried it the way you did but it just says "text [PAGE_OF_TOTAL]" in my PDF. I even redownloaded the Sejda 1.0.0 release from your link and it's still the same. Here is the line I'm using (sorry for the editing, i don't know how to do the code window ):     sejda-console setheaderfooter -f %%K\m2.pdf -o %%K\m3.pdf -s all -t Helvetica -d 10  -l "Seite [PAGE_OF_TOTAL]" -y bottom  -x left

Comment: Think you're running an old Sejda version that doesn't support [PAGE_OF_TOTAL] placeholders.

One of the first log outputs is the sejda version, could you confirm it's saying "Configuring Sejda 1.0.0.RELEASE"?

Comment: The first ouptput is: "09:22:05.312 Configuring Sejda 1.0.0.RELEASE
09:22:05.435 Loading Sejda configuration form default sejda.xml
09:22:06.323 Starting execution with arguments: ''
09:22:06.323 Java version: '1.8.0_60'
09:22:06.387 Sejda Console".

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. This feature is not in 1.0.0-RELEASE, only in the 2.x versions of Sejda. 

We haven't released any 2.x version that you can download and install yet, so you would need to build a sejda-console from source to use it right now.

Comment: As I am not good enough to build one on my own, I think I am going to wait for your 2.x version and leave it as a normal page number for now. Will it be possible to choose the language of [PAGE_OF_TOTAL], so for example "1 von 20" in german ? And I want to thank you for making sejda, it helped me alot so far :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've created https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/issues/187 for the internationalised [PAGE_OF_TOTAL]